# uwsgi gets Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, uwsgi

I totally have no idea what this Segmentation Fault. It's very very strange enough and it appears when visits increase.

> Sun Dec 20 22:24:56 2015 - error managing signal 3 on worker 3
>   DAMN ! worker 4 (pid: 22298) died :( trying respawn ...
>   Respawned uWSGI worker 4 (new pid: 22302)
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:56 2015 - error managing signal 36 on worker 3
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:56 2015 - error managing signal 15 on worker 3
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:56 2015 - error managing signal 50 on worker 2
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:56 2015 - error managing signal 37 on worker 3
>   !!! uWSGI process 22300 got Segmentation Fault !!!
>   *** backtrace of 22300** 
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x2e) [0x46949e]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x21) [0x469831]
>   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x35650) [0x7f40e9842650]
>   /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0xb) [0x7f40e9e4f03b]
>   /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x47) [0x7f40e9ee0fd7]
>   uwsgi(python_call+0x11) [0x47fd01]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_python_signal_handler+0x58) [0x47cae8]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_signal_handler+0x1db) [0x45d51b]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_receive_signal+0x2b) [0x45e52b]
>   uwsgi(wsgi_req_accept+0x2e0) [0x41f440]
>   uwsgi(simple_loop_run+0xb6) [0x465836]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_ignition+0x194) [0x469a84]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_worker_run+0x2dd) [0x46e2bd]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_run+0x3e4) [0x46e814]
>   uwsgi() [0x41e67e]
>   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f40e982eaf5]
>   uwsgi() [0x41e6a9]
>    **end of backtrace ***
>   DAMN ! worker 5 (pid: 22300) died :( trying respawn ...
>   Respawned uWSGI worker 5 (new pid: 22303)
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:57 2015 - error managing signal 20 on worker 2
>   ……
>   !!! uWSGI process 22303 got Segmentation Fault !!!
>   !!! uWSGI process 22302 got Segmentation Fault !!!
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:58 2015 - error managing signal 2 on worker 1
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:58 2015 - error managing signal 9 on worker 1
>
> Sun Dec 20 22:24:58 2015 - error managing signal 23 on worker 1
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:58 2015 - error managing signal 31 on worker 1
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:58 2015 - error managing signal 45 on worker 1
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:58 2015 - error managing signal 7 on worker 1
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:58 2015 - error managing signal 8 on worker 1
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:58 2015 - error managing signal 25 on worker 1
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:58 2015 - error managing signal 30 on worker 1
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:58 2015 - error managing signal 35 on worker 1
>   Sun Dec 20 22:24:58 2015 - error managing signal 21 on worker 1
>   *** backtrace of 22303** 
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x2e) [0x46949e]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x21) [0x469831]
>   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x35650) [0x7f40e9842650]
>   /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0xb) [0x7f40e9e4f03b]
>   /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x47) [0x7f40e9ee0fd7]
>   uwsgi(python_call+0x11) [0x47fd01]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_python_signal_handler+0x58) [0x47cae8]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_signal_handler+0x1db) [0x45d51b]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_receive_signal+0x2b) [0x45e52b]
>   uwsgi(wsgi_req_accept+0x2e0) [0x41f440]
>   uwsgi(simple_loop_run+0xb6) [0x465836]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_ignition+0x194) [0x469a84]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_worker_run+0x2dd) [0x46e2bd]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_run+0x3e4) [0x46e814]
>   uwsgi() [0x41e67e]
>   /usr/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f40e982eaf5]
>   uwsgi() [0x41e6a9]
>    **end of backtrace ***

Configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
vhost = true
processes = 5
max-requests = 1000
socket = 127.0.0.1:8002
pidfile = /data/myApp/uwsgi.pid
daemonize = /data/myApp/logs/uwsgi.log
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
daemon = true
module = django.core.wsgi:get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: What does your configuration look like? What amount of traffic are we talking about?

Comment: hi henrikstroem, thanks for your comment. And the traffic is about 100 visits per second. Not a really big one... But it's often <defunct>. And this is the configuration:

Comment: > [uwsgi]
> master          = true
> vhost = true
> processes       = 5
> max-requests = 1000
> socket          = 127.0.0.1:8002 
> pidfile         = /data/myApp/uwsgi.pid
> daemonize       = /data/myApp/logs/uwsgi.log
> chmod-socket    = 664 
> vacuum          = true  
> daemon          = true
> module = django.core.wsgi:get_wsgi_application()

Comment: Depending on your application, with 100 visits per second, the `max-requests` setting might be too low, but I really never had an issue with this. Try remove this line to let uWSGI apply the default, and see how that works. A couple of things though: you might want to use a UNIX socket rather than a network socket, this will give you less overhead. If you do, you should carefully consider the security setting in `chmod-socket`.

Comment: @henrikstroem Thx. I'll try it.

Comment: It's working perfectly since I deleted `max-requests = 1000`. Seems it's normal now. Hope that would not happen again. Much thanks for your suggestion, @henrikstroem.